# How to join table twice

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to join my `signatories` table twice but it is not displaying results as the rest of the tables:

```
SELECT a1.company, 
    a1.po_box, 
    a1.town, 
    l1.address_id, 
    l1.attn, 
    l1.create_date, 
    l1.ref_no, 
    l1.refference, 
    l1.letter_body, 
    l1.print_date 
FROM address_details a1 
inner join letter_details l1 ON a1.id = l1.address_id 
inner join signatories s1 ON l1.signature_id1 = s1.id 
inner join signatories s2 ON l1.signature_id2 = s2.id 
WHERE l1.id='" .$_GET[id] . "'";
```

My `signatories` has the following fields which I need be displayed.

- `id`
- `name`
- `deperatment`
- `job_title`

Comment: Format your code as actual code, you can select it and press ctrl+k

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more precise and placed the question in the body. I also indented your code sample to be more readable and marked other inline code samples - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: do you need somwthing like this.  select a.x, a.y, b.z from table1 a, table1 b where a.id = b.parent

Comment: yes nick i aliased and it worked thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define which field to fetch from signatories as well. So, if you are fetching all fields from signatories then just add s1.* on your select statement or if you are fetching from both joins (s1 and s2) then you may need to alias them.

Comment: thank you i added the fields and it's working,i feel foolish.cheers

Comment: though it's only displaying one of the signatories out of 2.